# Unable to stop and disable firewalld using Ansible

Tags: ansible

This is my playbook to stop and disable firewalld  :

```
---
-  hosts : openstack
   connection : ssh
   remote_user : ec2-user
   become_method : sudo
   become : yes
   gather_facts : no
   tasks :
   - command: "{{ item }}"
     with_items:
     - systemctl stop firewalld
     - systemctl disable firewalld
```

**Error :**

```
failed: [ec2-52-87-240-155.compute-1.amazonaws.com] (item=systemctl stop firewalld) => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["systemctl", "stop", "firewalld"], "delta": "0:00:00.009282", "end": "2016-10-27 13:37:20.620051", "failed": true, "item": "systemctl stop firewalld", "rc": 5, "start": "2016-10-27 13:37:20.610769", "stderr": "Failed to stop firewalld.service: Unit firewalld.service not loaded.", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
failed: [ec2-52-87-240-155.compute-1.amazonaws.com] (item=systemctl disable firewalld) => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["systemctl", "disable", "firewalld"], "delta": "0:00:00.004876", "end": "2016-10-27 13:37:20.816710", "failed": true, "item": "systemctl disable firewalld", "rc": 1, "start": "2016-10-27 13:37:20.811834", "stderr": "Failed to execute operation: Access denied", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
```

Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Access denied, try with `root` user, or run command as `sudo`

Comment: I have already written that in my code.....**become_method : sudo**. Its considered as root user. Anyways, I tried it by using sudo in command too...It threw the same error. The first command threw the error ** Unit firewalld.service not loaded**

Comment: try `service firewalld stop` from command line and check wither it succeeds or not

Answer (score 2):

There a few things wrong with this playbook:

- don't set a `space` character between `parameter` and `:`
- use `service` module instead of `command` module

This should work:

```
---
- hosts: openstack
  connection: ssh
  remote_user: ec2-user
  become: True
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
   - name: Stop and disable firewalld.
     service:
       name: firewalld
       state: stopped
       enabled: False
```

Comment: I get this error........fatal: [ec2-52-87-240-155.compute-1.amazonaws.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Could not find the requested service \"'firewalld'\": "}

Comment: That indicates that `firewalld` is not installed on the node. If you want to write a playbook to ensure that firewalld is not running on a node you could add `ignore_errors: True` to the task parameters.

Comment: Yaa....I included the "ignore_errors". It ignored the error. But, how will that help me. Does it mean it has stopped the firewalld service??

Answer (score 1):

if firewalld not installed/not running you can simply ignore error message using "failed_when:"

To avoid Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg

```
- name: 'Disable firewalld Services'
   service:
     name: "{{item}}"
     state: stopped  
     enabled: no
   loop:
     - firewalld
   register: firewalld_service_disable
   failed_when: "firewalld_service_disable|failed and ('Could not find the requested service' not in firewalld_service_disable.msg)"
   ignore_errors: yes
   tags: test
```

Below is the anisble playbook execution output

```
# ansible-playbook main.yml --tags test

PLAY [all] **********************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************
ok: [ANSIBLECLIENTNODE]

TASK [hardening : Disable firewalld Services] ***********************
changed: [ANSIBLECLIENTNODE] => (item=firewalld)

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************

ANSIBLECLIENTNODE             : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

If your ansible version 2.9 and later , follow below "service_facts" method

```
- name: 'Populate service facts'
  service_facts:

- name: 'Disable firewalld Services'
  service:
    name: "{{item}}"
    state: stopped
    enabled: no
  loop:
   - firewalld
  when: ansible_facts.services[item] is defined
  ignore_errors: yes
```